# Minhash implementation how to find hash functions for permutations

Tags: algorithm, implementation, hash-function, minhash

I have a problem implementing minhashing. On paper and from reading I understand the concept, but my problem is the permutation "trick". Instead of permuting the matrix of sets and values the suggestion for implementation is: "pick k (e.g. 100) independent hash functions" and then the algorithm says:

```
for each row r 
    for each column c 
        if c has 1 in row r 
           for each hash function h_i  do
            if h_i(r) is a smaller value than M (i, c) then
            M(i, c) := h_i(r)
```

In different small examples and teaching [book](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3.pdf) they only use two or three hash functions in the form of (h = a*x + b mod p). Thats easy to find, but how to do in practice, how can I find 100 of such independent functions.

In a Java example [here](http://mymagnadata.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/minhash-java-implementation/) there are generated hash values only from one hash function instead of multi hash functions, independent of the row index. Where is the difference ?
My question is now how to find these independent hash functions or if there is an approach with only one hash function how to treat these values in the algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is using a parametric hash family such as Tabulation hashing functions(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulation_hashing)

In the book's example (a*x+b mod p) by choosing different sets of (a, b, p) you can have different hash function. One way to have independent hash functions is to choose  (a, b, p) prime/co-prime and preferly large numbers

Answer (score 0):

As per iampat's answer, you could use tabulation hashing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulation_hashing).

Another very efficient option that gives good results is to use a single good-quality hash function (such as FNV_1a) to produce a master-hash, and then modify that using 100 different combinations of XOR and bitroll.

To generate each hash, you take the master hash, bitroll it by a given distance, then XOR it with a given value. The bitroll and XOR values are randomly chosen for each of the 100 hash functions. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701052/how-many-hash-functions-are-required-in-a-minhash-algorithm) for more info.

Some people recommend a multiply instead of an XOR, in which case you may want to choose primes.